# What is the use of wchar_t in general programming?

Tags: c++

Today I was learning some C++ basics and came to know about `wchar_t`. I was not able to figure out, why do we actually need this datatype, and how do I use it?

Comment: It's used when `char` is not enough, for example when using Unicode characters and strings.

Comment: you'll need it, if you want to work with sanskrit characters in your program, for example

Comment: [some people](http://utf8everywhere.org/) think you shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: how can we use wchar_t as string ?can we display the whole  string based on that character ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`wchar_t` is intended for representing text in *fixed-width*, *multi-byte* encodings; since `wchar_t` is usually 2 bytes in size it can be used to represent text in any 2-byte encoding.  It can also be used for representing text in *variable-width* multi-byte encodings of which the most common is UTF-16.

On platforms where `wchar_t` is 4 bytes in size it can be used to represent any text using UCS-4 (Unicode), but since on most platforms it's only 2 bytes it can only represent Unicode in a variable-width encoding (usually UTF-16).  It's more common to use `char` with a variable-width encoding e.g. UTF-8 or GB 18030.

About the only modern operating system to use `wchar_t` extensively is Windows; this is because Windows adopted Unicode before it was extended past U+FFFF and so a fixed-width 2-byte encoding (UCS-2) appeared sensible.  Now UCS-2 is insufficient to represent the whole of Unicode and so Windows uses UTF-16, still with `wchar_t` 2-byte code units.

Answer (score 17):

`wchar_t` is a wide character. It is used to represent characters which require more memory to represent them than a regular `char`. It is, for example, widely used in the Windows API.

However, the size of a `wchar_t` is implementation-dependant and not guaranteed to be larger than `char`. If you need to support a specific form of character format greater than 8 bits, you may want to turn to `char32_t` and `char16_t` which are guaranteed to be 32 and 16 bits respectively.

Answer (score 9):

`wchar_t` is used when you need to store characters with codes greater than 255 (it has a greater value than `char` can store).

`char` can take 256 different values which corresponds to entries in the ISO Latin tables. On the other hand, wide char can take more than 65536 values which corresponds to Unicode values. It is a recent international standard which allows the encoding of characters for virtually all languages and commonly used symbols.

Comment: ASCII is only 7 bit wide, and characters above 127 don't belong to ASCII. Unicode contains more than 65536 characters, and `sizeof(wchar_t)` is greater than 2 on many platforms. I've corrected your post.

Answer (score 4):

I understand most of them have answered it but as I was learning C++ basics too and came to know about `wchar_t`, I would like to tell you what I understood after searching about it.

1. `wchar_t` is used when you need to store a character over ASCII 255 , because these characters have a greater size than our character type 'char'. Hence, requiring more memory.

   e.g.:

   ```
          wchar_t var = L"Привет мир\n"; // hello world in russian
   ```
2. It generally has a size greater than 8-bit character.
3. The windows operating system uses it substantially.
4. It is usually used when there is a foreign language involved.

Comment: > wchar_t is used when you need to store a character over ASCII 255

Not necessarily true, a char encoded with UTF-8 can store all Unicode characters since a UTF-8 character can occupy one or more code points. However, Windows treats a narrow string as locale-specific so you'll have to use wchar_t instead.

Comment: There is no such thing as "ASCII 255." ASCII stops at 127. Also C defines `char` as never negative while leaving its signedness as undefined, so `char x = 255;` has Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The **wchar_t** data type is used to display `wide characters that will occupy 16 bits`. This datatype occupies "2 or 4" bytes.

Mostly the `wchar_t` datatype is used when international languages like japanese are used.

Answer (score 3):

`wchar_t` is specified in the C++ language in [[basic.fundamental]/p5](http://basic.fundamental#5) as:

> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales ([[locale]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/locale)).

In other words, `wchar_t` is a data type which makes it possible to work with text containing characters from *any* language without worrying about character encoding.

On platforms that support Unicode above the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), `wchar_t` is usually 4 bytes (Linux, BSD, macOS).

Only on Windows `wchar_t` is 2 bytes and encoded with UTF-16LE, due to [historical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows) (Windows initially supported UCS2 only).

In practice, the "1 `wchar_t` = 1 character" concept becomes even more complicated, due to Unicode supporting combining characters and graphemes (characters represented by sequences of code points).

Answer (score 1):

The wchar_t type is used for characters of extended character sets. It is among other uses used with wstring which is a string that can hold single characters of extended character sets, as opposed to the string which might hold single characters of size char, or use more than one character to represent a single sign (like utf8).

The wchar_t size is dependent on the locales, and is by the standard said to be able to represent all members of the largest extended character set supported by the locales.