# Why u8'A' can be a char type while UTF-8 can be up to 4 bytes and char is normally 1 byte?

Tags: c++

I was reading [What is the use of wchar_t in general programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509733/) and found something confusing in the accepted answer:

> It's more common to use char with a variable-width encoding e.g. UTF-8 or GB 18030.

And I find this from my textbook:

[image]

Isn't Unicode encoding with UTF-8 is at most 4 bytes? `char` for most platforms is 1 byte. Do I misunderstand something?

---

Update:

After searching and reading, now I know that:

1. code points and code units are different stuff. Code point is unique while code units rely on encoding.
2. u8'a'(a char, not string here) is only allowed for basic character set(the ASCII and it's control character stuff), and its value is the corresponding 'a''s code unit value, and for ascii characters, code units are same value as code points. (This is what **@codekaizer**'s answer say)
3. `std::string::size()` returns code units.

So the editors are all dealing with **code units** right? And If I change my file encoding from utf8 to uft32, then size of `ə` would be **4**?

Comment: The book is a slight but a nonetheless pragmatic simplification (C++ knows nothing about Unicode) but it is broadly correct, particularly on the sizes. Yes sizeof(char) is fixed at 1.

Comment: @Bathsheba C++11 supports unicode  u8"UTF-8 string."
u"UTF-16 string."
U"UTF-32 string."

Comment: Relevant to understand how "big" code points are mapped to many code units: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44998716/214671

Comment: UTF8, UTF16 and UTF32 are encodings of Unicode *code points*. It can take multiple code points to describe a single user visible "character" (or "grapheme cluster"), so even in UTF-32, care must be taken when splitting or concatenating strings.

Comment: Also see [What is the point of the UTF-8 character literals proposed for C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31970111/1708801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing code points with code units.

In UTF-8 each *code unit* (≈ data type used by a particular encoding) is one byte (8 bit), so it can be represented in a C++ program by the `char` type (which the standard guarantees to be at least 8 bit).

Now, of course you cannot represent all Unicode *code points* (≈ character/glyph) in just a single code unit if it is so small - they are currently well over 1 million, while a byte can have only 256 distinct values. For this reason, UTF-8 uses more code units to represent a single code point (and, to save space and for compatibility, uses a variable length encoding). So, the  code point (U+1F600) will be mapped to 4 code units (f0 9f 98 80).

Most importantly, C++ almost everywhere is concerned just with code units - strings are treated mostly as opaque binary blobs (with the exception of the 0 byte for C strings). For example, `strlen` and `std::string::size()` will all report you the number of code units, not of code points.

The `u8` cited above is one of the rare exceptions. It's an indication to the compiler that the string enclosed in the literal must be mapped from whatever the encoding the compiler is using to read the source file to an UTF-8 string.

Comment: Hey Matteo, thanks a lot! I can understand most of your answer now. I've updated some newcoming problem in the question, would you like to take a look? Btw, I read the post you commented and `ə` should be 2 code units, 2 bytes. But somehow I get 1 with `string s = "ə"; cout<<s;`.

Comment: @Rick: assuming you meant `cout<<s.size()`, on my machine it's 2 as expected, as well as on https://ideone.com/DLujdt; what compiler are you using?

Comment: yes, `s.size()`. I checked that on my mac air and it's 2. Something weird with my Visual Studio. I save a source file as UTF8(with signature) and still get a complie code page error.

Comment: Hey, Matteo. Would you like to take a look at this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363707/vc-compiler-source-charsetutf-8-doesnt-work I asked.

Comment: _"There are currently over 1 million"_... actually, they reduced it to a little over 1 million (`0x110000` or 1114112₁₀). That is not likely to change any time soon. We have a little over 15,000 characters defined in Unicode 14.0.

Answer (score 6):

> Isn't unicode encoding with utf8 is at most 4 bytes?

As per [lex.ccon/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#3), **emphasis mine**:

> A character literal that begins with u8, such as u8'w', is a character
>   literal of type char, known as a UTF-8 character literal. The value of
>   a UTF-8 character literal is equal to its ISO 10646 code point value,
>   provided that the code point value is representable with a **single
>   UTF-8 code unit** (that is, provided it is in the C0 Controls and Basic
>   Latin Unicode block). If the value is not representable with a single
>   UTF-8 code unit, the program is *ill-formed*. A UTF-8 character literal
>   containing multiple c-chars is *ill-formed*.

Single UTF-8 code unit is 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

The UTF-* is a family of variable encodings. On UTF-8, for instance, the minimal size is indeed 1 byte, but some characters require more. Those encodings have two advantages:

1. Compatibility with widespread characters types such as char
2. Minimal size when the text contains mostly English characters (which occupy 1 byte).

On the down size, variable length encodings require more work for some operations, e.g. calculating the number of characters in a given string. Since each character can occupy a different number of bytes, you can't just look at the string size (in bytes).

Given that, if you're going to use a variable length encoding, it usually makes sense to use the most compressed one, which is UTF-8 (under the assumption your text indeed contains mostly English characters). OTOH, if your text contains a wide range of languages, which will make UTF-8 inefficient, you can opt for the fixed size Unicode representations. On such cases, you'll need wider character types - 2 or 4 bytes.

Comment: Wait. I know utf8 but I am confused about that why `char`  can be used to represent utf8. I think char is not enough!

Comment: @Rick a single char isn't _always_ enough. When it isn't, a single character requires a sequence of a few chars. So there's no direct mapping between a single `char` and a single _character_ anymore in such encodings. But determining whether the `char` you're looking at is a single _character_ or the beginning of a multi-`char` representation is well specified in the encoding specs.

Comment: Are you sure there is a 2 byte fixed size unicode chars? AFAIK only utf32 enables random access.

Comment: UCS-2 is a fixed 2 byte encoding. That obviously severely limits the number of characters it can contain comparing to the UTF-* family. There's also UCS-4, which is identical to UTF-32.

Answer (score -2):

The character set is not restricted to the ASCII table only. Having entries which can reside in 1 byte. Usually the character is more than that when it comes to different languages e.g Japanese. These characters don't reside in the ASCII table so we use 4 byte for a character in that regard.

In C++ we assume that our character is in the ASCII table so we give it a size of 1 byte.

Comment: "In C++ we assume that our character is in the ASCII table". Really? The C++ standard doesn't.

Comment: The normal encoding of a character in C++ is of 1 byte.
That's why one byte of memory is allocated to a character in C++

Comment: It's the ASCII bit I'm particularly calling out.

Comment: ASCII has 256 characters which makes one byte. So I guess it's quite understood why in C++ there is one byte memory for a character.

Comment: Stop saying ASCII in other words. C++ is set up to support other character encodings. And ASCII is a 7 bit encoding, not 8 bit. This is clearly not your area of expertise. -1.

Comment: Extended ASCII!
Can you explain why a character is 1 byte in C++ if only 7 bits are required by ASCII.

Comment: try allocating a datatype with 7 bit. i think this will not work. there is also an `unsigned char`, but usually the thing you know as "character" is a (signed) `char`

Comment: @Saramali C++ does not specify the character set, and some C++ implementations will use other character sets, for example, EBCDIC on IBM z/OS. There are also implementations with different numbers of bits in a char, for example, Unisys 1100 mainframes where a char was 9 bits and old Cray systems where char was the same size as an int. Embedded CPUs for signal processing can also have "unusual" sizes for a char.

Comment: Extended ASCII is not a character set or character encoding. It's an attribute of many. But it's not a particularly useful attribute to know about a character encoding.