# VC++ compiler /source-charset:utf-8 doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, utf-8, encode

While I am experimenting code units under utf-8 in Visual Studio, I entercountered many pitfalls:

1. By default, VS save the source file with system region related encoding, for me , it's GB2312(codepage 936, a Chinese encoding).

   Solution: I use *save as* and save the file with UTF-8 without signature.
2. Then I found that by default the compiler interpret the source file with system region related encoding too, which it's still GB2312, so I got puzzling warning and syntax error.

   Solution: I use `/source-charset:utf-8` to compile, no warning and error. But the size result it's **2**('知' in GB2312 is encoded with 2 code units). But it should be **3** under utf-8.

'知' Unicode reference
https://unicode-table.com/en/77E5/

**(I think one can use any character that both exist in your current system encoding and utf-8 but with different code unit size to make a similar test.)**

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int main(){
        string s = "知";
        cout << s.size() <<endl;
        cout << s << endl;
    }
```

Moreover, the Windows cmd as well as powershell use the system region related encoding too (type `chcp` in cmd). So I can't print characters like `ə`.

So there's three stuff I need to take care about:

1. Source file encoding
2. Whether the compiler interpret the source file as expected
3. The cmd may not be able to display the character even if 1. and 2. are satisfied.

Besides, I have some confusion derived from this experience:

1. Why Windows acts like this? Can it just set everything with utf-8? I copied the same file to Mac and everything works as expected. And it's very easy to set Mac's terminal encoding.
2. Some posts I found said the reason is that some encoding standards (like this GB2312) are created before utf-8 come out. And many of them are not compatible with utf-8. So it continues to use for compatibility.

   But I wonder how the incompatibility would occur?   e.g. I download [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and install all the language packages. My system's encoding is GB2312, but I can still change the display language of NotePad++ to Japanese and it displays well. Not such thing like `????`.

Comment: Essentially, the windows console with UTF-8 is in a horribly sad state of affairs. IIRC you *can* make it work, but you have to suffer every bit of it; search StackOverflow for "windows console UTF-8" and enjoy the sadness that ensues. In general, support for UTF-8 in Win32 is spotty to say the least. The "official" unicode-aware APIs are UTF-16, and setting the thread locale to UTF-8 is apparently broken here and there (even though windows does support other variable length encodings just fine). The CRT also adds extra bugs to the mix.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, I searched that already. But the outcome for chaning that is so unpredictable and I gave up.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Is there any other "terminal" supports utf-8 under windows that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "source charset" is no coincidence here. The C++ standard explicitly differentiates between the (basic) source character set (96 common characters, all found in plain ASCII) and the execution character set.

Since you used UTF-8 as the source character set, `知` is mapped to `\u77E5`.

At runtime, however, you're using the *execution character set*. The VC++ `/source-charset` option does not affect VC++'s execution character set; for that there is an `/execution-charset`

But as @Matteo Italia already notes, the VC++ runtime is known to be more than a little bit flaky when it comes to UTF-8 I/O. `std::string.size` should work but `std::cout` might not.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. And I can the correct output under Git Bash.

Comment: Nice catch about `/execution-charset`, I didn't know about it!

Comment: @MatteoItalia Hey Matteo, do you know that are the `/source-charset` and `/execution-charset` setting available for all compilers or VC++ compiler only?

Comment: It's VC++ only, but IIRC g++ has something similar as well, although it has saner defaults so I didn't really use them.