# Is there literally any difference between String and Null-terminated character array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

Wanted to ask are strings are null-terminated character arrays interchangeable in c.
Like

```
    char string3[] = "abc";
    char string4[4] = {'a','b','c','\0'};

    if(!strcmp(string3,string4)){
        printf("yes");
    }
```

Even the strcmp also gives Yes. So, there is only the difference in initialization or is there some difference deep down there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char string3[] = "abc";
char string4[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
```

The main difference is that the string literal initializer consists of a sequence of multi-byte characters, whereas the array initializer list consists of a sequence of integer constant expressions each of which is formed from a multi-byte character constant. If any of the characters were not representable by a single `char`, their contents would be different. `string3[]` would be longer than 4 bytes and `string4[]` would be exactly 4 bytes long but with the values of some of its elements truncated. It shouldn't affect the characters `a`, `b`, `c` which are part of the basic character set and should therefore fit in a single `char`.

For example, on my system where C uses UTF-8 as the source and execution character set<sup>1</sup>, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string1[] = "αβγ";
    char string2[] = { 'α', 'β', 'γ', '\0' };
    printf("sizeof string1 = %zu, sizeof string2 = %zu\n",
        sizeof string1, sizeof string2);
    return 0;
}
```

compiles (with warnings<sup>2</sup>) and produces the output:

```
sizeof string1 = 7, sizeof string2 = 4
```

The warnings from gcc 10 were:

```
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:6:21: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    6 |  char string2[] = { 'α', 'β', 'γ', '\0' };
      |                     ^~~
foo.c:6:21: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘52913’ to ‘-79’ [-Woverflow]
foo.c:6:27: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    6 |  char string2[] = { 'α', 'β', 'γ', '\0' };
      |                          ^~~
foo.c:6:27: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘52914’ to ‘-78’ [-Woverflow]
foo.c:6:33: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    6 |  char string2[] = { 'α', 'β', 'γ', '\0' };
      |                               ^~~
foo.c:6:33: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘52915’ to ‘-77’ [-Woverflow]
```

If the execution character set is assumed to be UTF-8<sup>1</sup>, the string literal intializer `"αβγ"` could be changed to an array initializer list by expanding out each character as its sequence of bytes:

```
    char string5[] = { '\xce', '\xb1', '\xce', '\xb2', '\xce', '\xb3', '\0' };
```

If the array initializer needs to be a UTF-8 sequence regardless of the execution character set, it would be more readable to use an explicit `u8`-prefixed string literal initializer:

```
    char string6[] = u8"αβγ";
```

The initial contents of `string5[]` and `string6[]` are the same regardless of execution character set, and will be the same as the initial contents of `string1[]` if and only if the execution character set is UTF-8.

---

<sup>1</sup> By *"character set"* I really mean a character set plus an encoding, with the character set inferred from the specified encoding. I.e. by "UTF-8" I mean the UCS character set plus the UTF-8 transfer encoding.

<sup>2</sup> Compilers are not required to issue any diagnostic message when compiling the given example, but some choose to do so.

Comment: If you wanted to do that multi-character strings, you would use `wchar_t` not `char`. So if `string1` and `string2` used `wchar_t`, there'd be no difference. There is no difference between an array of characters (wide or not) vs. a `null-terminated` string literal (wide or not). UTF-8 vs. UTF-16 are encodings of the character array/string.

Comment: @Brandon But the whole point of UTF-8 is that you do *not* necessarily have to rewrite every line of code to use `wchar_t`.  And, as Ian's example shows, there can be quite a difference, in practice, between a null-terminated string literal, versus an array initializer like `{ 'α', 'β', 'γ', '\0' };`.

Comment: @Brandon On some systems (\*ahem\* MS Windows \*ahem\*) even `wchar_t` cannot encode every Unicode character as a single `wchar_t`, so the same sort of thing applies.

Comment: @Brandon For example `wchar_t wstring1[] = L"";` versus `wchar_t wstring2[] = { L'', L'\0' };` are not identical on MS Windows.

Comment: My point was that if you're not ignoring the compiler warnings and overflow warnings, they are the exact same. A string is literally an array of characters. If `wchar_t` cannot hold the character, then use a wider type like `char32_t` from `<uchar.h>`. The locale and encoding has nothing to do with whether or not a string is a character array. For example for `Windows` when your string literal cannot hold, use `char32_t` with `U"αβγ"` as in: https://ideone.com/CS5zoG Now they are equivalent. For all string literals, and char arrays not ignoring compiler warnings, they are the same thing.

Comment: @Brandon I guess I'm still not understanding your point. Maybe not under a Windows compiler, but on a machine like Ian's where the source character set is UTF-8, the declarations `char string1[] = "α"` and `char string2[] = { 'α', '\0' };` are simply *not* the same.  Nor is it a matter of ignoring warnings or not, since the `string1` declaration elicits no warnings.

Comment: @Brandon My point was to illustrate the places where that fails. Compilers are not required to produce a diagnostic for use of multi-character or single multi-byte character literals, or for out-of-range conversions of integer constant expressions to `char` (at least if `char` is an unsigned type).

Comment: @Brandon I guess you're saying, "On a machine where `char string2[] = { 'α', '\0' }` would fail or generate warnings, you should change `char string1[] = "α"` to `wchar_t string1[] = "α"`, and then they are the same."  But I would never change `char` to `wchar_t` for this reason, because `char string1[] = "α"` works fine.

Comment: We may be up against a fundamental practical difference between Windows and the rest of the world, which is that in the Windows world, as I understand it, internationalization requires switching to `wchar_t` everywhere, whereas the rest of the word is just using [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: @Brandon No one is saying that strings and arrays aren't the same.  The question is whether string-style and array-style initializers always behave the same.

Comment: @SteveSummit `α` is two `1-byte` characters. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#3 `The encoding-prefix of a non-encodable character literal or a multicharacter literal shall be absent or L.`. You realize the `α` is being encoded as two characters in the string literal form. Your array initializer isn't the same thing at all. It is ill-formed and would correctly be `0x03, 0xB1` for `α`. The string-literal is just the compiler doing that for you. In the array case, the compiler sees a `char` and decides to `overflow` the multi-byte character to fit it.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that a string literal is any different from a null-terminated character array. It just means that you are creating the array incorrectly and this is a user error. A single UTF-8 character is not supposed to overflow the unsigned type (unsigned char in this case), otherwise the program is ill-formed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343319/1462718 If you created the array with the character encoded correctly as 2 bytes for each of those, it will be the exact same as the string-literal initializer.

**Clang gives an error vs GCC:** https://i.imgur.com/UDaDsL9.png

Comment: @Brandon I wasn't claiming that you couldn't initialize the `char` array with an initializer list to match the bytes of the string literal initializer. I was illustrating that the naive re-edit of a string literal initializer to an array initializer list of character constants (using the same character glyphs as in the string literal) doesn't always produce the same result.

Comment: @Brandon I added more stuff about initializers for UTF-8 sequences (see `string5` and `string6` in the answer).

Answer (score 5):

```
char string3[] = "abc";
```

is exactly short for

```
char string4[4] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
```

and there is no difference.

However, note that

```
//  now it's a pointer
//   |
//   v
char *string3b = "abc";
```

and

```
char string4[4] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
```

are **not** equivalent. Whenever you write a string and don't initialize an array with it (pointers are not arrays), the compiler creates an array for you. The first one is basically equivalent to:

```
static const char _magic_compiler_variable_for_abc_string[4] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
char *string3b = (char*)_magic_compiler_variable_for_abc_string;
```

so the string is allocated somewhere else and `string3b` only holds a pointer to it. Because the string variable is `const` (even though the pointer is not const), you are not allowed to edit the string in this case. The compiler may use the same `_magic_compiler_variable_for_abc_string` everywhere you write `"abc"`, or it may create separate ones.

Comment: "you are not allowed to edit the string in this case." is more like it is UB to attempt to edit.   It might work, might not, might ...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'd say, that's exactly what "you are not allowed to" means!  You are not allowed to modify string literals, you are not allowed to cross the intersection when the light is red, etc., etc.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, it is giving Segmentation fault