# How does a C compiler parse code like `arr[]`?

Tags: c, gcc, cc

It is well known that function declarations like

```
void foo (int arr[])
```

and

```
void foo (int* arr)
```

are identical since array variables are just pointers to the first element of the array.

My question is about how a C compiler processes the first version. Does it work just like other compiler directives (`#define`) and simply substitute for the second?

Comment: It's implemenation-dependent, but not likely to be done like macro substution, because there are many different formats. So after it parses the program into a parse tree, the code generator for both formats produces the same code.

Comment: Think of it like this. If your brother's name is Joe, you understand the sentences "Joe is a great guy" and "Your brother is a great guy" to mean the same thing. The compiler understands that both of these declarations mean the same thing in a function parameter list.

Comment: There is no simple substitution that allows this to work. `void f(double a[restrict static 3][5]);` is a valid declaration according to C99 6.7.5.3.21

Comment: `void foo (*arr)` is a syntax error

Comment: there is a semantic rule that a function parameter with array type is adjusted to pointer type , before further analysis . It's not part of the grammar

Comment: @M.M Oops, I totally forgot the data type. Thanks for pointing that out :) Regarding your other comment, would it be possible to flesh that out in answer? It seems to be different than the other comments made above I think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> … array variables are just pointers to the first element of the array.

They are not. There are contexts in which an array is converted to a pointer to its first element, but an array is not just a pointer to its first element, and it cannot be because there are contexts in which an array is not converted to a pointer to its first element. The compiler must distinguish between an array and a pointer until sufficient context is resolved.

For purposes of specifying C semantics, in declarations of function parameters, a declaration of an array is automatically adjusted to be an declaration of a pointer. However, that adjustment is a conceptual act. It does not have to be implemented in a particular way in a compiler. It can be implemented in various ways, or the necessary semantics can be provided without any actual adjustment.

For example, when a parameter is declared to be a pointer, the compiler has to do certain things such as:

- When the function is called, the compiler must check the rules applicable to passing an argument for a pointer parameter and may need to convert the argument to the parameter type.
- In the function definition, the compiler must process references to the parameter as references to a pointer object.

Now, when a parameter is declared to be an array, the compiler can implement the semantics required by the C standard by fully processing the declaration and constructing its own internal representation of the declared identifier and then adjusting that internal representation to represent a pointer type. However, another way for the compiler to implement the semantics is to keep the internal representation unchanged but process it using the same rules it would for a pointer parameter:

- When the function is called, check the rules applicable to passing an argument for a pointer parameter and, if applicable, convert the argument to the pointer type corresponding to the declared array type.
- In the function definition, the compiler process references to the parameter as references to a pointer object.

So, there are multiple ways a compiler can implement the behavior required by the C standard.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Much of it went above my head and that's because I likely need to read a book on compilers at some point. At any rate, "There are contexts in which an array is converted to a pointer to its first element, but an array is not just a pointer to its first element, and it cannot be because there are contexts in which an array is not converted to a pointer to its first element" was very helpful for me. I suppose this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574524/is-there-literally-any-difference-between-string-and-null-terminated-character-a) is one such case?